# Sitecore content showing in Experience Editor only

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Sitecore content showing in Experience Editor only. Why or how could this be happening?

Comment: You haven't published templates or items with the content. Login to Sitecore, go to Desktop, switch to Web db and check if all your content is there

Answer (score 0):

Your content, templates or layouts are not published to web db.
Experience editor points to master db so you created content but you have not published.

Switch to web db and check whether all the content available or not.